# Use a std::vector or std::set for sorted and no duplicate elements?

Tags: c++

I want a container for holding about a ~3K to 5K `int` type elements. I want them to be sorted and there should be no duplicates. However, I am not using `std::find` to find an element in them. I am simply using an iterator to sequentially loop over them.

Would it be better use a `std::set` here? Or, a vector to first insert all elements, then remove duplicates and sort them?

What's the efficient way to sort and remove duplicates from `std::vector` if it should be preferred over a `std::set`?

Comment: I think it depends on how often you need to sort and remove duplicates. Just once? Or do you have to update the data? It also depends on how you use the data. For example, do you iterate over it in tight loops? In the end you have the meassure to be absolute sure.

Comment: Yes, Just once. No updates needed.

Comment: Test up to about 100,000 integers `std::vector` is fastest (better than set and list) See 45:48 in https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2014/2-661

Comment: This (admittedly a few years old) presentation may shed some light on the matter: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LrVi9LHP8Bk (building a sorted collection starts around 35 min in. (Traversal is addressed about 11 min in)

Answer (score 2):

`std::set` is slow and uses a lot of memory, because it is a dynamic data structure with every node containing pointers.

Get the best of both worlds by using Boost's `flat_set`.  It stores in a sorted vector, but contains the API like `set` so it automatically removes duplicates and keeps them in sorted order.

I think you'll find that a contiguous `vector` (as used by `boost::containers::flat_set`) will be faster than the `std::set` up to 10,000 elements at least (rule of thumb; modify if your elements are slow to move).  You can improve it by using `reserve` before you start.

Comment: Does `flat_set` sort on every insertion, or does it wait until a lookup occurs?

Comment: I've not looked at the code, but I'm pretty sure it maintains sorted upon adding an element.  That is needed to prevent insertion of duplicates.  That is, even an insertion _is_ a lookup as well.  Note that it never needs to `sort`; just insert a single element into an already sorted vector.

Comment: Well, imagine I insert 1,000,000 elements to a container with 1,000,000 elements. It'd be way more costly to shift elements one-by-one a million times, instead of keeping track of how much of the container is not sorted until a lookup happens and then sorting it once.

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili If a lookup "never happened" that would help.  But when you do sort, it's n log n.  Inserting an element into a sorted list as you add them is log n, and you do that for each element, so it's also n log n.  In fact it's identical to an insertion sort.  The semantics of a set removes duplicates and the API tells you if insert was a duplicate and an iterator to the existing or added element.

Comment: Inserting anything in the middle of vector is O(n). So, inserting sorted becomes O(n log n). You do that for each element, it becomes O (n^2 log n).

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili you're right, insertion sort is quadratic.  For sufficiently many elements, using a different sort (i.e. quicksort) all at once would be faster than keeping it in sorted order.  I suppose that the form of `insert` that takes an entire range of elements to add at once could make this optimization.  Otherwise you would need to define a container with different semantics and API to allow it to be lazy.

Answer (score 1):

You should run a couple benchmarks to see which is better in your case. I did [one](https://quick-bench.com/q/_q-3firQGLebrNzfx89FIGsaCvw) myself:

```
#include <vector>
#include <set>
#include <random>
#include <limits.h>

std::vector<int> GetRandArray(std::size_t const sz)
{
  std::mt19937 engine {std::random_device{}()};
  std::uniform_int_distribution<int> dist {INT_MIN, INT_MAX};
  auto gen = [&dist, &engine]  { return dist(engine); };

  std::vector<int> vec(sz);
  generate(begin(vec), end(vec), gen);
  return vec;
}

auto const RandNumbers = GetRandArray(3'000);

static void Vector(benchmark::State& state) {
  for (auto _ : state) {
    std::vector<int> vec{ RandNumbers.begin(), RandNumbers.end() };
    std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end());
    vec.erase( std::unique(vec.begin(), vec.end()), vec.end() );
    benchmark::DoNotOptimize(vec);
  }
}
BENCHMARK(Vector);

static void Set(benchmark::State& state) {
  for (auto _ : state) {
    std::set<int> set{ RandNumbers.begin(), RandNumbers.end() };
    benchmark::DoNotOptimize(set);
  }
}
BENCHMARK(Set);
```

[image]

As you can see, with 3000 elements, vector obliterates set.

Answer (score 0):

The efficient way is sort + unique, that takes O(N * log N) time complexity and O(1) memory usage. sort can be omitted if the vector is already sorted, then the time complexity is O(N).

You find the description and usage examples here [std::unique](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/unique). It must be used after std::sort if the vector is not yet sorted.